# How to use ArrayFire's Forge visualization in custom area within existing Qt window or DC (Device Context) instead of separate window?

Tags: rendering, arrayfire

In real world applications we don't want to use a separate window for some plot, is there a way to use a control's DC or a way to use Qt QML as render target for the ArrayFire's Forge library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Forge in that fashion. You just have to avoid using forge::Window instances. You can still use all other renderable classes of Forge library while a valid OpenGL context is available. They will just render to the active view port.

Comment: Thanks. Are there possibly any example projects around?

Comment: I believe there was one Project that was using Qt itself actually. It was long time ago, I cannot recall who was that developer. I don't think it should be that hard if I remember correctly. It is mostly about calling object::render methods with right parameters when your existing Qt viewport is active. That is pretty much how forge also works, windows make sure there is active contect while the other objects handle render logic and assume there is active OpenGL context.